# How to save flash and actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, editing

I have a flash app (chat) with the sources, which is .fla and 7 .as files.
Project is saved in CS6.
I can edit what I want, but I have problem saving it. I have poor knowledge about flash and Action Script, so I need some help saving the project.
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to save your files? Which editor(s) are you using?

Comment: I open the .fla with Flash CS6 and Export Movie, result is loop from 1-st to last frame.

Comment: Well, it could be a bunch of things... bad syntax, not extending extending Sprite or MovieClip in your document class, or, since you have multiple frames, not using stop();  Does anything trace in the  output panel?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "compiler error" panel. If there's anything in there, Flash will refuse to execute any command and will just play the frames sequentially. If there's nothing there, the .fla file is probably not linked to the code in the first place. Look for the "class" attribute under "Properties" -> "Publish" and set to the name of the main .as file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not write the app on the first place. If you are trying to take some code & trying to learn from it (or get it to run), go step by step.

First find the entry point of the app. See any code in the timeline?? Anything on the frames?

- If yes, starting following it.
- If not, there would be a document class specified in the stage properties...start from there.

Beyond this, Share more details, for a better answer....